# WMI reports user logged in after logoff if a share was accessed during the session

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi

I'm using WMI inside c# to get a list of users currently "logged in" to a machine:

```
    ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);

    var q = new SelectQuery("Win32_LoggedOnUser");
    using (var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, q)) {
        using (var results = query.Get()) {
            foreach (var r in results) {
                using (var o = new ManagementObject(r["Dependent"].ToString())) {                     
                    var logonType = o["LogonType"];

                    if (logonType == "2") {
                        // Interactive user is logged in, retrieve the name
                        using (var userObj = new ManagementObject(r["Antecedent"].ToString())) {
                            name = userObj["Name"].ToString();                                        
                        }
                    }

                    ...
```

This works great, but it seems that in some cases even after the user logs out, WMI still reports it as being logged in.  One particular case is when that user accesses a network share during the session.

Is there anyway around this? Perhaps a way to test a session to see if it was created as a share or if it's active?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the user has logged off, because you accessed another computer's files remotely, the connection remains open for a period of time.

https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states

Look under Run > cmd > netstat -a. You should see a connection called microsoft-ds after you have established a connection through Windows Explorer to another computer. This is the service that Microsoft uses for file transfers, among other things. If you see a TIME_WAIT or CLOSE_WAIT, the connection is still open even if window you used to access the files is closed.

You can check this programmatically by using "handle.exe", a tool provided by Microsoft that is a part of Sysinternals, that will be able to provide information on which part of the hive is still active. This should include Registry Keys, ports, the works.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

WMI may be reporting that the user is still logged in because a port or connection has not been closed that was initiated by that user. This type of thing has caused us a few headaches, so we use handle.exe to dump anything keeping the hive open for a user and then systematically kill/close all of it before we do any profile maintenance (as an automation).

Of course, rebooting the computer always works. =)